# Какую логику должен включать в себя reducer, а какую action?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

К примеру у меня есть action:

```
export function addCar(carType) {
  return {
    payload: carType,
    type: ADD_CAR
  };
}
```

И соответсвующий ему reducer:

```
function addCar(state, action) {
  let { parkingPlace, truckPalce, disabledPlace, cars, sedanPlace } = state;
  const carType = action.payload;

  switch (carType) {
    case carsTypes.sedan:
      if (sedanPlace === 0 && truckPalce === 0) {
        swal('Error', 'No places for sedan', 'error');

        break;
      }

      if (sedanPlace !== 0) {
        sedanPlace--;
        parkingPlace--;
        cars.push({});

        break;
      }

      if (sedanPlace === 0 && truckPalce !== 0) {
        truckPalce--;
        parkingPlace--;
        cars.push({});

        break;
      }

      break;    

    case carsTypes.disabled:
      if (disabledPlace === 0 && sedanPlace === 0 && truckPalce === 0) {
        swal('Error', 'No places for disabled', 'error');

        break;
      }

      if (disabledPlace !== 0) {
        disabledPlace--;
        parkingPlace--;
        cars.push({});

        break;
      }

      if (disabledPlace === 0 && sedanPlace !== 0) {
        sedanPlace--;
        parkingPlace--;
        cars.push({});

        break;
      }

      if (disabledPlace === 0 && sedanPlace === 0 && truckPalce !== 0) {
        truckPalce--;
        parkingPlace--;
        cars.push({});

        break;
      }  

    case carsTypes.truck:
      if (truckPalce === 0) {
        swal('Error', 'No places for truck', 'error');

        break;
      }

      truckPalce--;
      parkingPlace--;
      cars.push({});

      break;
  }

  const newState = { 
    ...state, 
    parkingPlace,
    truckPalce,
    disabledPlace,
    sedanPlace,
    cars
  };

  localStorage.setItem('parking', JSON.stringify(newState));

  return newState;
}
```

Описание задачи:
Когда машина заезжает на парковку, у нее есть тип Sedan, Disabled или Truck. 
На инвалидных местах могут парковаться только инвалидные машины.
На обычных местах могут парковаться только обычные машины или инвалидные.
На грузовых местах могут парковаться все виды машин, но приоритет инвалидкам и грузовым в первую очередь.

Так вот стоит ли выносить логику (switch, условия) в action ?

Comment: disabled - это инвалидка??

Comment: самое смешно что так написано в задании, да

Comment: Да не, не смешно. Выходит, что инвалид - действительно disabled. Не знал просто, думал invalid так и будет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**reducer** - это функция, которая отвечает за определенный участок состояния приложения. Другими словами, только эта функция знает что делать с переданными вместе с `action` данными, а так же отвечает за иммутабельность (неизменяемость) состояния.

**action** - это объект, который служит для передачи данных в `reducer`.

**action creator** - это функция которая в которой происходит создание данных для `reducer`, которые попадут в него с помощью `action`.

Так вот вся логика выносится в `action creator` ( я не имею ввиду что прям туда, естественно нужно делать декомпозицию ). Поэтому лично я бы вынес определение типа `action` именно в `action creator`.

**UPD:** хочу отдельно сказать что если логика нужная для создания `action` слишком примитивная, то её можно реализовать прямо в `action creator`. Ну а в тех случаях в которых логики вообще нет `action creator` не создается вовсе.

Answer (score 2):

Недавно стал изучать связку react/redux и попробую ответить на некоторые вопросы и дать советы, если я не прав, пускай меня поправят более опытные люди.

> К примеру у меня есть action:
>
> export function addCar(carType) {   return {
>       payload: carType,
>       type: ADD_CAR   }; }

Тут все верно, только **action** - это js-объект, который возвращает ваша функция

```js
{
  payload: carType,
  type: ADD_CAR   
}
```

а addCar() - это генератор действий (**Action Creator**) и его основное назначение вернуть action, который является единственным источником инфы для Store.

**Action** сигнализирует хранилищу что случилось что-то  ("добавилась машина" - ADD_CAR, тип машины - carType). Не нужно перегружать его логикой работы приложения. Генераторы должны быть легкими и переносимыми.

Если я правильно понял логику, каждая въезжающая машина может забрать какое-то место на парковке согласно своему типу или получить сообщение, что мест нет.

Логика, которую вы хотите использовать в приложении, на мой взгляд лучше создать на серверном api, к которому будет обращаться **action creator**.

Допустим в POST-запросе на `myparking.com/api/cars` вы отправляете тип машины (`седан`), сервер проверяет инфу по местам и отдаем вам ответ (`занимай седан-место`, `занимай грузовик-место` или `гуляй - мест нет`)

Этот ответ получает генератор событий (**action creator**) - чисто условно выглядит так:

```js
export const getPlace = () => dispatch => {
    dispatch({
        type: GET_PLACE_REQUEST,
        isLoading: true
    });

    $.ajax(`api/cars/`).then(
        function(response) {
            dispatch({
                type: GET_PLACE_SUCCESS,
                response: response,
                isLoading: false
            });
        }
    )
};
```

пускай вам не смущает такая форма записи, я скопировал пример из своего кода с минимумом изменений. Это тот же генератор, он сначала запрашивает место, а потом получает ответ сервера с результатом.

Потом в **reducer**'e (он отвечает за смену состояния, в зависимости от типа **action**) вы вернете результат

```js
export default function cars(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_PLACE_REQUEST:
            return { ...state, isLoading: action.isLoading };

        case GET_PLACE_SUCCESS:
            return { ...state, response: action.response, isLoading: action.isLoading };

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

здесь уже **reducer** получит ответ в заданной вами форме, от простого - `забирай место` или `гуляй`, до сложного - `выделено место типа TYPE, номер места -NNN, длительность парковки - YYY часов`, который вы же разберете и используете для отображения.

Логика уйдет на сервер, а в редьюсере вы будет просто менять состояние и он не будет перегружен как сейчас

Применительно к вашему нынешнему коду, оставляйте логику в reducer'e, хотя это очень спорное решение. Но в качестве концепта - пойдет, со временем вы сами захотите эти исправить.

Можно, конечно, послать учить [официальную документацию](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/) по redux, но вот несколько ресурсов, которые помогли мне быстрее въехать в тему

- [пару статей по связке react/redux](https://www.gitbook.com/@maxfarseer) на русском
- [перевод документации redux](https://github.com/rajdee/redux-in-russian) на русский

Comment: Абсолютно согласен с вами, мне написали что редюсер перегружен, я и давай думать что тут не так )

Comment: @KhoteyVitaliy дополнил ответ

Comment: Только, пожалуйста, не используйте jQuery для AJAX запросов. Давно уже есть fetch, который намного удобней. Единственный его минус - нельзя сделать abort и это все.

Comment: @alexes спасибо, учту